# Using GITHUB_TOKEN inside Docker to run Maven on GHA

Tags: java, docker, maven, github-actions, github-package-registry

**Context:**

I have a Github Action (GHA) that creates a Docker image and send it to AWS.

This image contains a `Java` application that is built with `Maven` and have a **dependency** from **Github Packages**, which is only accessible using a personal github token (or a *generic github token* on GHA).

Running my application locally (without docker), I should setup my maven `settings.xml` to use my personal github user and token.

Maven `settings.xml` file, inside `user/.m2` directory:

```
<settings>
    ....
    <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>USER</username>
      <password>TOKEN</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Running with Docker, I copy this `settings.xml` to docker and it works.

```
    FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-focal

    WORKDIR /app

    RUN mkdir -p /root/.m2 \
        && mkdir /root/.m2/repository
    COPY settings.xml /root/.m2
   
    RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
    ....
   
    CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

Running with GHA, I saved my personal user/token in secrets and used it on this `settings.xml`

```
  - name: exchange secrets on settings.xml
  env:
    GH_PERSONAL_USER: ${{ secrets.GH_PERSONAL_USER }}
    GH_PERSONAL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PERSONAL_TOKEN }}
  run: envsubst < settings.xml.j2 > settings.xml
```

Some docs I found, but didn't help me:

- [github_token in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#using-the-github_token-in-a-workflow)
- [authenticate to a GitHub Packages registry within a GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry)

**My problem/question:**

I don't want to store/use my personal user/token as a secret on this repository, and I know that Github have a `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` for these cases, but I don't know how to use it on maven `settings.xml` file, that requires a **token** and **user**.

Is there a way to use this `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN`?

Comment: See https://maurocanuto.medium.com/using-github-private-packages-and-maven-in-github-actions-c9e2ea69e2bc - it seems the username doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks!, I tried here and that's it, username doesn't matter.